# CFFI cannot find functions even though they are in the library

Tags: python, shared-libraries, wrapper, word-wrap, python-cffi

**I am trying to load a shared library using CFFI. The code is meant to instantiate a C structure, print it and destroy it.**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from cffi import FFI
ffi = FFI()

ffi.cdef("""
            typedef struct
            {
                int numero;
                const char* message;
            }STRUCTURE, *PSTRUCTURE;

            PSTRUCTURE CreateStructure();
            int PrintStructure( PSTRUCTURE );
            int FreeStructure( PSTRUCTURE );
        """)

lib = ffi.dlopen("./lib/libstructure.so")

structure = lib.CreateStructure()
lib.PrintStructure( structure ) 
lib.FreeStructure( structure )
```

**But I am getting this error:**

username@Ubuntu1204VB:~/tests/cffi_tests/structure$ python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 22, in 
    structure = lib.CreateStructure()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cffi/api.py", line 810, in __getattr__ make_accessor(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cffi/api.py", line 806, in make_accessor accessors[name](name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cffi/api.py", line 751, in accessor_function raise AttributeError('%s: %s' % (name, e))
AttributeError: CreateStructure: "function 'CreateStructure' not found in library './lib/libstructure.so': ./lib/libstructure.so: undefined symbol: CreateStructure"

**So, I have checked what is inside ./lib/libstructure.so, using nm -DC:**

@Ubuntu1204VB:~/tests/cffi_tests/structure$ nm -DC ./lib/libstructure.so
................................ w _Jv_RegisterClasses
0000000000000731 T FreeStructure(STRUCTURE*)
0000000000000702 T PrintStructure(STRUCTURE*)
00000000000006bc T CreateStructure()
0000000000201028 A __bss_start
................................ w __cxa_finalize
................................ w __gmon_start__
0000000000201028 A _edata
0000000000201040 A _end
0000000000000788 T _fini
0000000000000588 T _init
................................ U free
................................ U malloc
................................ U printf

**CreateStructure seems to be there.**

So I created a C main to test the library and it worked. But, I had to include the library and the header (./include/structure.h) of the source code I used to create the shared library (./src/structure.cpp).

Then, I copied and pasted the header into the source code I used to create the shared library, as I could not find a way to load it with the library in the Python code, and built the shared library again. Unfortunately, I am still getting the same error while executing python. This means the issue is not coming from the potentially missing header file.

Hence, I would like to know if I could check the symbols from the python code, after they are loaded using ffi.dlopen("./lib/libstructure.so"), to make sure that they are properly loaded... or not.

Any way to do this? Anything I am missing here?

**EDIT : Investigation**
I have added the following function to my source code:

```
int main(void)
{
    return printf("%d\n", 42);
}
```

And "int main(void)" in ffi.cdef, over CreateStructure's prototype.
When I only call lib.main()... it prints 42... If I change int main(void) for int test(void) and call lib.test(), it gives me the error "undefined symbol: test"...
If I change the name of my other functions to "main" (one at a time), they work properly. It is as if cffi could only consume functions named "main"...

**EDIT : Answer to comments**
I am getting the following error using `make` in `simple-example/` :

```
username@Ubuntu1204VB:~/tests/python-cffi-example-how-cffi-works/simple-example$ make  
clang -shared add.c -o libadd.so  
clang -L. -ladd add-example.c -o add-example.exe  
/tmp/add-example-r7jvhJ.o: In function \`main': add-example.c:(.text+0x25): undefined reference to `add'  
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)  
make: \*** [add-example.exe] Error 1
```

Note that I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and that I have just installed clang using sudo apt-get install clang.

Also, here is the makefile I used to compile the shared library:

```
CC = gcc
INC_PATH = -I ./include

DEBUGFLAGS = -g
CFLAGS = -c -fPIC $(DEBUGFLAGS) -Wall -Wextra
LDFLAGS = -fPIC $(DEBUGFLAGS) -Wall -Wextra -shared
OBJS = ./obj/structure.o
TARGET_LIB = ./lib/libstructure.so
RM = rm -f

all: $(OBJS) $(TARGET_LIB)

./obj/structure.o : ./src/structure.cpp
    $(CC) $(INC_PATH) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

./lib/libstructure.so : $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

.PHONY:
clean:
    -${RM} ${TARGET_LIB} ${OBJS}
```

Comment: That is very strange. Everything you're doing looks correct… so if I had to guess, I'd say it's something strange to do with how the library and/or cffi was compiled, possibly? Try checking out the `how-cffi-works` branch of https://github.com/wolever/python-cffi-example — after running `make` in the `simple-example/` directory, does `python add-example.py` work? Code: https://github.com/wolever/python-cffi-example/tree/how-cffi-works/simple-example

Comment: Question edited to answer your question.

Comment: Yep, there's definitely something funky going on somewhere in the toolchain then. If you've got gcc installed you could try replacing `CC=clang` with `CC=gcc` then running `make clean; make` to see if that works. Otherwise I'm not sure what the issue would be, since the `libadd.so` seems to have the same problem.

Comment: The first problem is that libstructure.so is compiled with C++, not with C.  You see this by "nm" producing names like "CreateStructure()" with parenthesis and possibly argument types. CFFI expects the C name "CreateStructure" instead.  Calling C++ code from CFFI is not directly possible.  You can call C code that itself calls C++ code, though.

Comment: @Armin @David Thank you, it works. The only thing I changed is the name of the file... from `structure.cpp` to `structure.c`. I did not think its extension would make a difference in a makefile, as I was using GCC on Ubuntu! However, this does not explain the issue I had while compiling `simple-example`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the fix :

Armin Rigo pointed out that `nm` showed the code was compiled as C++, by displaying functions like `CreateStructure()` instead of functions like `printf` from the C standard library (note the parenthesis presence, because C++ depends of arguments for name mangling and C does not allow multiple functions with the same name).

Thus, to compile with C, the name of the source file had to be changed from `structure.cpp` to `structure.c`, because file extensions matter with GCC.